# rsync output only the files transfered/deleted

Tags: rsync

I am running rsync in a cronjob and redirect the output of rsync in the cronjob using

```
/opt/rsync.sh ... > /var/log/rsync.log 2>&1
```

I know, I can make rsync output just a summary of number of bytes transferred and so on. I also know I can make rsync verbose printing the percentage of each file transferred. But when I redirect the verbose output into a file, it produces a list of outputs for each file since it frequently sends the percentage to stdout.

How can I get something in between, print every file transferred and a summery but not multiple lines for the process percentage of each file?

Comment: show us an example output how you get it and how you expect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are doing rsync and redirecting STDOUT to a file - something like

```
rsync -avz mydir targetserver: > rsync.log
```

If that's so, then you can simply use the argument `--log-file=rsync.log` to tell it to write to said logfile directly instead of using STDOUT. So the command line above can instead be

```
rsync --log-file=rsync.log -avz mydir targetserver:
```

Another option would be to remove the `--progress` option from the rsync command, so that the percentage does not show.

For a script, it might make more sense to replace the `--progress` with an output format that lists what type of changes have been made. That's easily done using  the `itemize-changes` option. From the man page:

> -i, --itemize-changes
>
> Requests a simple itemized list of the changes that are being made to each file, including attribute changes.  This is  exactly  the  same  as  specifying --out-format='%i %n%L'.  If you repeat the option, unchanged files will also be output, but only if the receiving rsync is at least version 2.6.7 (you can use -vv with older versions of rsync, but that also turns on the output of other verbose messages).

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using a cronjob, I am using rsync from a script that also outputs more stuff. I have it clarified in my question.

Comment: I've added info about how you could change the output instead.